# Configure CSS module class name in Vue project with Vite js

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, css-modules

In my `vite.config.ts` I have a config for CSS modules

```
return defineConfig({
 ...
  css: {
    ...
    modules: {
      localsConvention: "camelCase",
      generateScopedName: "[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:2]"
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    vue()
  ]
});
```

As a result, I get this kind of class names
[Output of CSS module class name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eYEX.png)

However, it generates an unnecessary string between the component name and the local class name (something like this) `-vue-vue-type-style-index-0-lang-module`
How can I get rid of it and have a format like `ComponentName__class_hash`

I tried to use a function for this `generateScopedName` property, but I could not set the hash for each class
https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#css-modules

Answer (score 0):

To configure the CSS module class name in a Vue project with Vite.js to have a format like `ComponentName__class_hash`, you will need to customize the `generateScopedName` function in your `vite.config.ts` file. You can use the `name` and `local` variables to construct the class name in your desired format.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import crypto from 'crypto';

export default defineConfig({
  // ... other configurations
  css: {
    modules: {
      localsConvention: 'camelCase',
      generateScopedName: (name, filename, css) => {
        let componentName = filename
          .replace(/\.\w+$/, '')
          .split('/')
          .pop(); 

        // Generate hash
        const hash = crypto
          .createHash('md5')
          .update(css)
          .digest('base64')
          .substring(0, 5); 

        return `${componentName}__${name}__${hash}`;
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
});
```

Comment: Tested, does not work. Class `test` in `AboutView.vue` is generated to `AboutView.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang.module__test__50UU` using this method. Apart from that, the style is not applied anymore when rendered in the browser.

Comment: Did you resolve this by any chance? I am trying this same method as the above and getting the same result, class names generated correctly but no styles